# Angularjs autocomplete JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, autocomplete

I'm very new to Angular and I've been doing tutorials and reading books.  I'm trying to get an autocomplete from a JSON result.  I got the JSON result to iterate over a table, but I need to be able to search with autocomplete based off of that same JSON result.

I have a Plnkr below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VObrSPu94rS3dGyVqaXk

Answer (score 1):

If you pop open your developer console, you'll see that there is an error being thrown from your `ngAutocomplete.js` file. It looks like that directive is designed to be used for [Google Places](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) and is expecting you to have a Google library loaded as well.

You probably want to look for a more generic autocomplete directive. The only one I've used is the typeahead included in the [Angular UI Bootstrap project](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead), but there are a number of [autocomplete modules](http://ngmodules.org/tags/autocomplete) on the Angular Modules site (the one you are using is the second one listed) that may work for you.

Comment: Actually the typeahead library from the angular-ui/bootstrap doesn't require Bootstrap's JS nor JQuery. It only needs bootstrap's CSS for _the default templates_, but those can be easily customized to work with _any_ markup / CSS: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#customize-templates

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource - Thanks for the correction. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

As Sean says, [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) ([Typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)) is a good option.
Here is a [specific tutorial for that feature](http://williamverdolini.github.io/2014/01/30/discitur-Autocomplete_en/) from my project.