# Autocomplete textbox from json in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have only basic experience in AngularJS.

Here is a AngularJS script which autocomplete a textbox from given list of countries. But I need it to read data from a local Json file.

Got confused totally because my Json file contain nested Json objects.
When I search 'AAL or Aalb' in the textbox I need to see AAL-AALBORG as a listed.

Can somebody please brief explain me how to do it?

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
    app.controller("usercontroller", function ($scope) {
        $scope.countryList = ["USA", "UK", "INDIA","KOREA"];
        $scope.complete = function (string) {
            var output = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.countryList, function (country) {
                if (country.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                {
                    output.push(country);
                }
            });
            $scope.filterCountry = output;
        }
            $scope.fillTextbox = function (string) {
            $scope.country = string;
            $scope.hidethis = true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML is,

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="usercontroller">
            <label>Enter a country</label>
            <input type="text" name="country" id="country" ng-model="country" ng-keyup="complete(country)" class="form-control"/>
        <ul class="list-group" ng-model="hidethis" ng-hide="hidethis">
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="countrydata in filterCountry" ng-click="fillTextbox(countrydata)" >{{countrydata}}</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Nested Json format is:

```
{"AAL":{"id":"32313","airport_name":"Aalborg","latitude":"57.1","longitude":"9.85","timezone":"2","dst_indicator":"E","city":"Aalborg","country":"Denmark","country_code":"DK","region":"TC1","listing_display":"true","pseudonyms":""},"AAR":{"id":"32314","airport_name":"Tirstrup","latitude":"56.15","longitude":"10.2167","timezone":"2","dst_indicator":"E","city":"Aarhus","country":"Denmark","country_code":"DK","region":"TC1","listing_display":"true","pseudonyms":""}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs autocomplete JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482584/angularjs-autocomplete-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Final Script as per suggestions, Thanks all :



    var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
    app.controller("usercontroller", function ($scope,$http) {
        $http.get('js/airport.json').then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.countryList = response.data;
            })
        $scope.complete = function (string) {
            var output = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.countryList, function (country, code) {
                if ((code.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0) | (country.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0)) {
                    output.push(code + "-" + country.city);
                }
            });
            $scope.filterCountry = output;
        }
            $scope.fillTextbox = function (string) {
            $scope.country = string;
            $scope.hidethis = true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $http service.

```
$http.get('path_to_your_json_file').then(

 function success(data){
    $scope.myArray = data;
}
```

)

Comment: sorry, countryList array mentioned above is another one. I am still searching how to load nested json objects to array.

Answer (score 0):

On init of your component, fill a data array with this data, when the user write in the input, get the value using keyup for instance. If your autocompleteData exists && your length > 0 then you can display a table under your input.

To filter, I would use something like :

```
filter(company: Airline){ 
    this.companyTable.filter((company) => {
      return company.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(valueFilter.toLowerCase()) >= 0 
});
```

Where company is a company from your companyTable, and valueFilter the word in the input (you can access using DOM / ElementRef, see doc)

Comment: Explained well. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: You're welcome, there is too much code to write for what you want to do, but the main part filter function is here. If you need more help let me know. By the way, I forgot the >= 0 at the end of the return statement which means show me only the relevant match, if -1 you have no result found.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
$scope.countryList = {"AAL":{"id":"32313","airport_name":"Aalborg","latitude":"57.1","longitude":"9.85","timezone":"2","dst_indicator":"E","city":"Aalborg","country":"Denmark","country_code":"DK","region":"TC1","listing_display":"true","pseudonyms":""},"AAR":{"id":"32314","airport_name":"Tirstrup","latitude":"56.15","longitude":"10.2167","timezone":"2","dst_indicator":"E","city":"Aarhus","country":"Denmark","country_code":"DK","region":"TC1","listing_display":"true","pseudonyms":""}};
```

try this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.countryList, function (country, code) {
            if ((code.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0) | (country.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0))
            {
                output.push(code +"-" +country.city);
            }
        });
```

Comment: best way will be to use custom filter.

Comment: Good, Appreciated..!! Could you please show me , how to load same json file from local to a countryList array.  I tried it, but not working

Comment: use $http as suggested by @Kenany